# register and create new user in firebase in ionic 2

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am working on an ionic 2 project I want to add register and create an new user  using email and password in firebase auth

my `register.html` page is as given

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (submit)="doRegister()" novalidate>
    <ion-item margin-bottom>
      <ion-input
        type="text"
        formControlName="name" placeholder="Name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item margin-bottom>            
      <ion-input
        type="email"
        formControlName="email" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item margin-bottom>
      <ion-input
        type="password"
        formControlName="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button block type="submit">
      Register
    </button>
```

`register.ts` is as follows

```
export class RegisterPage {

  public registerForm;
  submitAttempt: boolean = false;
  loading: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authService: AuthProvider, public navParams: NavParams, public formBuilder: FormBuilder,public alertCtrl: AlertController, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    let EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;
    this.registerForm = formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(EMAIL_REGEXP)])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])],
      name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])]
    });
  }

  doRegister() {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((auth : any) =>
    {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
      console.log(email,password);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
        alert('The password is too weak.');
      } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);         
    });
  }
}
```

but it does not create the user it's giving me following error.

```
There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
```

any help?

Comment: Off topic, but Angular has a built in email validator which could allow you to get rid of the Regex. https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator

Comment: Additional note - have you seen `angularfire2`. It's a wrapper which can be installed on ionic to allow easier connectivity with Firebase.

Comment: how to use can you plz give the solution

Answer (score 0):

All Firebase signup methods only save the users under Authentication tab. You have to specifically create user after successful signup by calling the set method like this

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
```

read more about create & update here [Read and Write Data on the Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=1)

**Note:** this URL is for firebase web usage. Make sure to switch to the desired tab (ios, android also language specific) from left sidemenu